# Can I get the last inserted row that a trigger created, inside of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a stored procedure that updates a record. Our DBA created a trigger that updates that row and deactivates the record. It then creates an identical record, but with an active flag and it receives a new auto generated PK. So it goes something like this:

```
PK=1, Active=1, Data='test' --> PK=1, Active=0, Data='test' --> PK=2, Active=1, Data='test2'
```

But in my stored procedure, which calls the update, I need to get the last row that the trigger inserted.

Is it possible?

Here is my update code:

```
UPDATE [OASIS].[dbo].[TT_PEQHeader]
    SET 
    [LastUpdateDate] = GETDATE()
    ,[LastUpdateBy] =@intUserPK
    ,[ID] = @vchID
    ,[Description] = @vchDescription
    ,[CompletionRate] = @dcCompletionRate
    ,[IndustryExperiance] = @intIndustryExperiance
    WHERE PEQHeaderPK= @intPEQHeaderPK

    SELECT * FROM vw_TT_PEQHeader WHERE PEQHeaderPK = @intPEQHeaderPK
```

I'm currently getting the record based on the PK sent to the SP. That's what I need to change.

Here's the trigger code:

```
USE [OASIS]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_TT_PEQHeader]
   ON  [dbo].[TT_PEQHeader]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @dPEQHeaderPK AS INT
    Declare @dLastUpdateDate AS DATETIME
    Declare @dLastUpdateBy AS INT
    Declare @dID AS VARCHAR(25)
    Declare @dDescription AS VARCHAR(50)
    Declare @dVersion AS INT
    Declare @dPreviousVersionPK AS INT
    Declare @dActive AS BIT
    Declare @dCompletionRate AS DECIMAL(18,2)
    Declare @dIndustryExperiance AS INT
    Declare @NewPEQHeaderPK AS INT

SELECT 
@dPEQHeaderPK =a.PEQHeaderPK, 
@dLastUpdateDate = a.LastUpdateDate, 
@dLastUpdateBy = a.LastUpdateBy, 
@dID = a.ID, 
@dDescription = a.Description,
@dVersion = a.Version, 
@dPreviousVersionPK = a.PreviousVersionPK, 
@dActive = a.Active, 
@dCompletionRate = a.CompletionRate, 
@dIndustryExperiance = a.IndustryExperiance 
FROM INSERTED a
INNER JOIN deleted ON a.PEQHeaderPK = deleted.PEQHeaderPK    

/*Deativate the old record*/
Update TT_PEQHeader SET Active = 0 where PEQHeaderPK = @dPEQHeaderPK

IF(@dActive = 1)        
BEGIN
    /*Copy and paste a new PEQH record*/
    INSERT INTO TT_PEQHeader
        SELECT GETDATE(),@dLastUpdateBy,GETDATE(),@dLastUpdateBy,@dID,@dDescription,@dVersion + 1,@dPEQHeaderPK,1,@dCompletionRate,@dIndustryExperiance

    SELECT @NewPEQHeaderPK = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    /*Copy and paste a new batch of PEQD records*/
    INSERT INTO TT_PEQDetail
        SELECT GETDATE(),@dLastUpdateBy,GETDATE(),@dLastUpdateBy,@NewPEQHeaderPK,QuestionID,QuestionText FROM  TT_PEQDetail WHERE PEQHeaderFK = @dPEQHeaderPK
END 
END
```

Comment: What is your stored proc and trigger code?

Comment: @Rachcha I updated the post with the code.

Comment: Often you would put all of that logic in one SP. Why did the DBA do it separately in a trigger? Is it a business requirement or a technical auditing requirement? Also I take it there is much more trigger code - that would have to be in a cursor that loops within the INSERTED table. Post ALL the code.

Comment: @Rachcha I'm not sure why he did it this way. I think it maybe he was focused just on the database side of things instead of the whole picture. I added the rest of the trigger code. But there's really not much else to it. It's mostly boiler plate stuff you'd expect. No cursor or anything. So do you think the best course of action is just to do all of it in the SP? The only time this table would be updated is at my stage.

Comment: How about CONTEXT_INFO for a _bad_ idea? Have a look [here](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2010/01/exploiting-context_info-for-fun-and-audit/) for someone going the other way.

Comment: If that trigger was written by your DBA, then the good news is that he's (or she's) an idiot. `inserted` and `deleted` can contain *multiple* rows, and `SELECT @dPEQHeaderPK = ...` is going to assign values for only *one* of those rows and ignore all of the others.